# Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to header in PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, cors

I am trying to workaround CORS restriction on a WebGL application. I have a Web Service which resolves URL and returns images. Since this web service is not CORS enabled, I can't use the returned images as textures.

I was planning to:

1. Write a PHP script to handle image requests
2. Image requests would be sent through the query string as a url
   parameter

The PHP Script will:

1. Call the web service with the query string url
2. Fetch the image response (web service returns a content-type:image response)
3. Add the CORS header (Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to the
   response
4. Send the response to the browser

I tried to implement this using a variety of techniques including CURL, HTTPResponse, plain var_dump etc. but got stuck at some point in each.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is the approach good enough?
2. Considering the approach is good enough:

I made the most progress with CURL. I could get the image header and data with:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = $_GET["url"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:image/jpeg'));

//Execute request 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

//get the default response headers 
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

//close connection 
    curl_close($ch);
```

But this doesn't actually change set the response content-type to image/jpeg. It dumps the header + response into a new response of content-type text/html and display the header and the image BLOB data in the browser.

How do I get it to send the response in the format I want?

Comment: Isn't the cURL code you have after `curl_exec()`, (`$headers = curl_getinfo($ch); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`) unnecessary?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest approach turned out to be the answer. Just had to insert the header before sending the response off.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $_GET["url"];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

//Execute request 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

//get the default response headers 
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

//close connection 
    curl_close($ch);
    flush();
```

Answer (score 7):

make sure that Apache (if you are using Apache) has **mod_headers** loaded before using all that stuff with headers.

(following tips works on Ubuntu, don't know about other distributions)

you can check list of loaded modules with

```
apache2ctl -M
```

to enable mod_headers you can use

```
a2enmod headers
```

of course after any changes in Apache you have to restart it:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

after this try adding this line to your .htaccess, or of course use php headers

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```