# Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on source server

Tags: php, jquery, apache, rss, cors

I am using `$.get` to parse an RSS feed in jQuery with code similar to this:

```
$.get(rssurl, function(data) {
    var $xml = $(data);
    $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                author: $this.find("author").text()
        }
        //Do something with item here...
    });
});
```

However, due to the Single Origin Policy, I'm getting the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Fortunately I have access to the source server, as this is my own dynamically created RSS feed.

My question is: how do I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on my source server?

**Edit**

I'm using PHP and I think my webserver is Apache.

Comment: What server-side language are you using? What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP and I *think* the webserver is Apache - my hosting is with 1&1.

Comment: You have two options. Add a .htaccess file that sets the header, or have php return the file with the header. Plenty of examples here: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to header in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630589/add-access-control-allow-origin-to-header-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For apache, you simply add this to a .htaccess file in the same directory as the file you are trying to access remotely.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Turns out the PHP option worked for me in this instance (`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`), but thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Set it right in the php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: This worked great for me. Is there any security advantage to having the access in the single php file over adding it to .htaccess for the site?